# listbox selecteditem error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

There have an error

> "Object Reference not set to an
>   instance of an object"

when using `objusername.intuserid=listbox1.selecteditem.value`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `listbox1.SelectedItem` is null, or `listbox1.SelectedIndex = -1` before accessing the property. This basically means nothing is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Your ListBox1 can also return Text using SelectedValue property iff value has set to that before. But above is more effective way to get text.

Now, the value is something that is not visible to user but it is used mostly to store in database. We don't insert Text of ListBox1, however we can insert it also, but we used to insert value of selected item. To get value we can use

```
ListBox1.SelectedValue
```